# All Apache virtual hosts shows default website page

Tags: apache, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

Here is a problem. I am running on CentOS 7 with Httpd(Apache) installed. After installation default DocumentRoot is ***/var/www/html***. And my site domain is avect.ru. Then I've created a virtual host with the link cp.avect.ru. But when I enter it, it shows content NOT from specified DocumentRoot ***/var/www/cp***, but ***/var/www/html***.

Idk why this happens. NameServers are not working, because they are deprecated. Help please! 
Here is part of httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cp.avect.ru
    ServerAlias *.avect.ru
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cp/
    ErrorLog /var/log/cp-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/cp-requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You must define 2 virtualhosts.  One for avect.ru, which points to /var/www/html.  Another one for cp.avect.ru, which points to /var/www/cp.  And remove the ServerAlias *.avect.ru, this will mix up everything.  Here you only show 1 virtualhost, this will not work.

Comment: Actually before this post I've tried with 2 virtual hosts. That also didn’t work..